# Saltstack create user : password is not set

Tags: salt-stack

I am trying to automate the creation of my users with Saltstack.

I created a pillar conf:

```
users:
  homer:
    fullname: Homer Simpson
    uid: 1007
    gid: 1007
    groups:
      - sudo
      - adm
    crypt: $6H7kNJefhBeY
    pub_ssh_keys:
  - ssh-rsa ...
```

And in my state I use the following:

```
{% for username, details in pillar.get('users', {}).items() %}
{{ username }}:

  group:
    - present
    - name: {{ username }}
    - gid: {{ details.get('gid', '') }}

  user:
    - present
    - fullname: {{ details.get('fullname','') }}
    - name: {{ username }}
    - shell: /bin/bash
    - home: /home/{{ username }}
    - uid: {{ details.get('uid', '') }}
    - gid: {{ details.get('gid', '') }}
    - password: {{ details.get('crypt','') }}
    {% if 'groups' in details %}
    - groups:
      {% for group in details.get('groups', []) %}
      - {{ group }}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

  {% if 'pub_ssh_keys' in details %}
   ssh_auth:
    - present
    - user: {{ username }}
    - names:
    {% for pub_ssh_key in details.get('pub_ssh_keys', []) %}
      - {{ pub_ssh_key }}
    {% endfor %}
    - require:
     - user: {{ username }}
  {% endif %}

 {% endfor %}
```

The user creation is okay, ssh-rsa keys are added properly but my main isssue is with the password: I tried the following:

```
crypt: password
crypt: some-hash
```

But when I connect to my server, I have a wrong password issue for this user.

Can you tell me how can I generate a good password compliant with the format salt is expecting? Is there a special command to use to generate it ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

To create hashed user passwords in Debian/Ubuntu, usable in salt, I do the following:

```
apt-get install makepasswd
echo '<password>' | makepasswd --clearfrom=- --crypt-md5 | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

This gives e.g.: $id$salt$encrypted

The id in "$id$salt$encrypted" should be 1, meaning it's an md5 hash.

Copy/paste this hash into your pillar.

Hope this works for you as well.

Comment: // , Can you dynamically create credentials using SaltStack or its Pillar feature? Like HashiCorp Vault Dynamic Secrets? https://learn.hashicorp.com/vault/secrets-management/sm-dynamic-secrets

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use md5, which is denoted by $1

If you look in your /etc/shadow file and see other passwords are $6 then it is using sha-512.

Don't use makepassword, use "mkpasswd"

```
mkpasswd -m sha-512
Password: [enter password]
$6$fYewyeO5lMP/$CLbYqRdUootlGA3hJzXye84k0Of9VX4z39TOnsDxfIaFcL4uGznfJsGEJMiEaHKHZDSIUK7o4r22krvhezpZq1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks die the makepasswd example. It whould be great, if it works. But in my case it doesn't.

The hashed password seems not to be correct. Maybe another encryption should be used?

I have used the standard user formula from the salt stack GitHub repositories,